Find real solutions to equation
I would like to find symbolic expressions for $x$ which satisfy the equation
$$-(a \, x^2 - 2\, e\, d \, x)(a+b)\sqrt{a\, b\, (a^2\, x^2 - 2\,  a\, d\, e\, x - c\, d)} + 2\, b$$$$\,(a\, x - e\, d)\left(a^2\, x^2 - 2\,  a\, d\, e\, x - \dfrac{c\, d}{2}\right) = 0$$
whereby all parameters are postive real numbers. Symbolic expressions are required as they are evaluated many times for different parameter sets during the optimization of an electronic system. Additionally, they should be used for further calculation. The entire optimization procedure is implemented in Matlab. An exemplary parameter set could be $a=260,\, b=209,\, c=200,\, d=1.87,\ e=1$. In a first attempt, I had Maple solve the equation. However, if I replace the parameters in the solution with the given numbers, I only get complex results. If I plot the left part of the equation for $x$ values ranging between $]\frac{ed + \sqrt{a^2\, x^2\, + c\, d}}{a},\frac{1}{2}]$, I can see that there is a zero at $x\approx 0.181$, which is the one I am particulary interested in.
In a second attempt I brought the expression into a polynomial form and let it solve again. Same result. However, in either case the real part of one of the solutions matches the graphically obtained value very well while the imaginary part is quite small (1e-11 in Maple and 1e-17 in Matlab). I am wondering if this results from precision errors and why I am not able to obtain a "pure" real solution.
It's been a while since my last maths lecture and I'm not a Maple pro either. So I greatly appreciate any hint or help regarding my problem.

"In a second attempt I brought the expression into a polynomial form and let it solve again.", perhaps this should be included. How did you remove the radical?

The symbolic solver solve here produces the result in terms of radicals.
The presence of the imaginary unit in such roots (in radical form) is sometimes unavoidable.
Floating-point error (roundoff, loss of precision, etc) may result in small imaginary artefacts, if evaluating such results to floating-point approximation.
In some such cases (roots of a cubic, for example) the roots may be re-cast in a trigonometric form that does not contain radicals or the imaginary root. Floating-point evaluation/approximation of that form may avoid said imaginary artefacts.
But in Maple you might get a purely real floating-point answer even quicker by simply using fsolve instead of solve. If all you're after is a floating-point answer then why do all that symbolic heavy lifting?
I'll use 187/100 instead of 1.87, to keep the coeffcients exact and hopefully illustrate the points better.
restart;
ee := -(a*x^2-2*e*d*x)*(a+b)*sqrt(a*b*(a^2*x^2-2*a*d*e*x-c*d))
      +2*b*(a*x-e*d)*(a^2*x^2-2*a*d*e*x-c*d/2):

inst := eval(ee, 
             [a=260,b=209,c=200,d=187/100,e=1]);

   -469*(260*x^2-187/50*x)*(3673384000*x^2-52840216*x- 
   20323160)^(1/2)+418*(260*x-187/100)*(67600*x^2-4862/5*x-187)

Now, using a floating-point ("numeric") solver, whose default is to compute only real roots,
fsolve(inst, x=0..2);

           0.1812506325

Now, using the exact symbolic solver. Note the radicals and presence of the imaginary unit. The simplify command won't get rid of I here.
ansrad := solve({inst, x>0});

  {x = 187/26000+1/234000*33^(1/2)*((40* 
   (75884102645228324+1044697500*I*
   41757865119935835^(1/2))^(2/3)+5536793* 
   (75884102645228324+1044697500*I*
   41757865119935835^(1/2))^(1/3)+14865898803040)/
   (75884102645228324+1044697500*I*
   41757865119935835^(1/2))^(1/3))^(1/2)}

Floating-point evaluation/approximation shows these small imaginary artefacts, which get smaller as working precision is increased.
evalf(ansrad);

        /                                 -11  \ 
       { x = 0.1812506327 + 6.119105971 10    I }
        \                                      / 

evalf[10](evalf[20](ansrad));

        /                                 -21  \ 
       { x = 0.1812506325 + 5.712421874 10    I }
        \                                      / 

The evalc command can (it turns out) convert this root into a trig form, without radicals or I.
evalc(ansrad);

{x = 187/26000+1/43482753998892000*33^(1/2)*(185823735038*(14865898803040*cos(2
/3*arctan(261174375/18971025661307081*41757865119935835^(1/2)))+11073586*
92911867519^(1/2)*cos(1/3*arctan(261174375/18971025661307081*41757865119935835^
(1/2)))+14865898803040)*92911867519^(1/2)*cos(1/3*arctan(261174375/
18971025661307081*41757865119935835^(1/2)))+185823735038*(14865898803040*sin(2/
3*arctan(261174375/18971025661307081*41757865119935835^(1/2)))+11073586*
92911867519^(1/2)*sin(1/3*arctan(261174375/18971025661307081*41757865119935835^
(1/2))))*92911867519^(1/2)*sin(1/3*arctan(261174375/18971025661307081*
41757865119935835^(1/2))))^(1/2)}

evalf(%);

       {x = 0.1812506325}

Even nicer, that particular trig form result can be simplified,
simplify(evalc(ansrad));

{x = 187/26000+1/234000*33^(1/2)*(160*92911867519^(1/2)*cos(1/3*arctan(
261174375/18971025661307081*41757865119935835^(1/2)))+5536793)^(1/2)}

evalf(%);

      {x = 0.1812506325}

Lastly, a note of caution. Even if you can construct a symbolic representation of the root(s), it might not be the best idea if all you want at the end of the day is a float approximation with decent accuracy for given instantiations of the parameters by numeric values.
It's not just that the symbolic representation might be enormous. It's not just that it might be in radical form with an imaginary unit present. It might be even more serious that floating-point evaluation of such a instantiated beast might incur much more floating-point error. You might just be better off -- in terms of both time and accuracy -- to use a dedicated floating-point solver instead.

Unfortunately, a symbolic solution is required in a first step as obtaining a numerical value is only part of the problem. I edited my question accordingly for clarification. An enormous solution would be acceptable for me as parts of the solution occur repeatedly and can be expressed with intermediate values - after all, I was able to successfully solve similar problems with this approach. Precision is also not an issue for me. I am totally fine with an accuracy of 1e-3. Do you think this issue is solvable or do I have to live with the results I already got?

Did you see the compact exact result in my Answer, in terms of trig/arctrig? That was an exact result. (ps. Don't use float values up front for a symbolic solve.) You could even write a procedure that attempts to construct such for numeric arguments for the parameters. But this forum is about Mathematics, not Maple programming, and this it not the right place for that. Better would be stackoverflow.com or mapleprimes.com for Maple programming queries.
